# Essential singularity of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

How I can prove that if a holomorphic map $f:U-\lbrace z_0\rbrace\rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ is such that  $|f(z)|\leq C|z-z_0|^{-k}$ ($C$ is a constant)on a punctured neighbourhood of $z_0$, then $z_0$ isn't an essential singularity?

Comment: The growth condition on $f$ means that the Laurent series expansion of $f$ has only finitely many terms with negative exponent.

Comment: Hint: $(z-z_0)^kf(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z_0.$